# Why does PageButtonCount do not work when using PagerTemplate in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Below is code of a GirdView in which i've taken a PagerTemplate which is working fine except the attribute PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="3".
I wanted to display only three page numbers at a time which is normally accomplished by the PageButtonCount attribute.

**Asp.Net**

```
<asp:GridView
    id="grdMovies"
    DataSourceID="srcMovies"
    AllowPaging="true"
    PageSize="3"
    Runat="server" 
    PagerSettings-PageButtonCount="3"
    OnDataBound="grdMovies_DataBound">
    <PagerTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton
                    id="lnkPrevious"
                    Text="&lt; Prev"
                    CommandName="Page"
                    CommandArgument="Prev"
                    ToolTip="Previous Page"
                    Runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Menu
                    id="menuPager"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                    OnMenuItemClick="menuPager_MenuItemClick"
                    CssClass="menu"
                    Runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton
                    id="lnkNext"
                    Text="Next &gt;"
                    CommandName="Page"
                    CommandArgument="Next"
                    ToolTip="Next Page"
                    Runat="server" />
                </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C# Code**

```
 <script runat="server">
        protected void grdMovies_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Menu menuPager = (Menu)grdMovies.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("menuPager");
            for (int i = 0; i < grdMovies.PageCount; i++)
            {
                MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
                item.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
                item.Value = i.ToString();
                if (grdMovies.PageIndex == i)
                item.Selected = true;
                menuPager.Items.Add(item);
            }
         }
        protected void menuPager_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {
            grdMovies.PageIndex = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value);
        }
    </script>
```

How can i achieve this.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add this property in your gridview

```
PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast"
```

Comment: @AnilKumar did you find the answer? If yes, can you post here please